# Spaces cause split in path with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm having an issue with powershell when invoking an exe at a path containing spaces.

`PS C:\Windows Services> invoke-expression "C:\Windows Services\MyService.exe"`

> The term 'C:\Windows' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

It seems to be splitting on the space between 'Windows' and 'Services'. Any idea how to get around this problem?

Comment: Use [`&`, the call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#call-operator-), to invoke commands whose names or paths are stored in quoted strings and/or are referenced via variables, as in the accepted answer. `Invoke-Expression` is not only the wrong tool to use in this particular case, [it should _generally_ be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Would this do what you want?:

```
& "C:\Windows Services\MyService.exe"
```

Use [`&`, the call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#call-operator-), to invoke commands whose names or paths are stored in quoted strings and/or are referenced via variables, as in the accepted answer. `Invoke-Expression` is not only the wrong tool to use in this particular case, [it should *generally* be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

Comment: For me, I am passing the path as an -ArgumentList into Start-Process. Start-Process -FilePath "notepad++.exe" -ArgumentList "C:\Long Path\That\contains\many spaces\toThisFile.txt"

Answer (score 36):

You can escape the space by using single quotations and a backtick before the space:

```
$path = 'C:\Windows Services\MyService.exe'
$path -replace ' ', '` '
invoke-expression $path
```

Comment: Problem with this solution is that the path is passed in as an argument and I cannot control how it is escaped.

Comment: You can just perform `-replace` on the variable containing the path and replace ' ' with '` '

Comment: While this answers the question as asked, it's worth pointing out that `Invoke-Expression` is not only the wrong tool to use for the OP's use case, [it should _generally_ be avoided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

Answer (score 15):

Not sure if someone still needs it... I needed to invoke msbuild in powershell and following worked fine:

```
$MSBuild = "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"

& $MSBuild $PathToSolution /p:OutDir=$OutDirVar /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release
```

Answer (score 13):

```
"&'C:\Windows Services\MyService.exe'" | Invoke-Expression
```

via https://www.vistax64.com/powershell/52905-invoke-expression-exe-has-spaces-its-path.html

Answer (score 12):

For any file path with space, simply put them in double quotations will work in Windows Powershell. For example, if you want to go to Program Files directory, instead of use

```
PS C:\> cd Program Files
```

which will induce error,  simply use the following will solve the problem:

```
PS C:\> cd "Program Files"
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Using PowerShell v`7.3.0`

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
$scanresults = Invoke-Expression "& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\nmap.exe' -vv -sn 192.168.1.1-150 --open"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked to launch a powershell file named `wslLauncher.ps1` that was located in a path that contained a space, from Eclipse in Java. The exact line of code was: ```String command = "powershell.exe & '"+launcherPath+launcherName+"' ";```

Answer (score 9):

What worked for me (I needed the path to create a MySQL dump), was to place the directory in between 6 double quotes like so:

```
$path = """C:\Path\To\File"""
```

Answer (score 7):

Using Powershell on Windows10 in 2018, what worked for me was simply **to replace double quotes `"` by simple quotes `'`**. Adding the backtick before the space, as suggested in an answer, broke the path.

Comment: Works for me. If I use double quote, I get the error `ParameterArgumentValidationError`.

Answer (score 7):

Can use the `.` dot operator.

```bsh
. "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd"
```

or the `Start-Process` command

```bsh
Start-Process -PSPath "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code.cmd"
```

or using `ProcessStartInfo` and `Process`

```bsh
$ProcessInfo = New-Object -TypeName System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$ProcessInfo.FileName = 'C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
if($Admin){ $ProcessInfo.Verb = 'runas' }
$ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = $false

$CommandParameters = '-noexit -noprofile -command Set-Location -LiteralPath c:\; $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = ''[{0}] PS''; Set-PSReadlineOption -HistorySaveStyle SaveNothing;' -f $Cred.UserName
$ProcessInfo.Arguments = $CommandParameters
$ProcessInfo.Domain = ($Cred.UserName -split '\\')[0]
$ProcessInfo.UserName = ($Cred.UserName -split '\\')[1]
$ProcessInfo.Password = $Cred.Password

$ProcessObject = New-Object -TypeName System.Diagnostics.Process
$ProcessObject.StartInfo = $ProcessInfo
$ProcessObject.Start() | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a hack I've used since the Invoke-Expression works fine for me.

You could set the current location to the path with spaces, invoke the expression, get back to your previous location and continue:

```
$currLocation = Get-Location
Set-Location = "C:\Windows Services\"
Invoke-Expression ".\MyService.exe"
Set-Location $currLocation
```

This will only work if the exe doesn't have any spaces in its name.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Please use this simple one liner:

```
Invoke-Expression "C:\'Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16'\EXCEL.EXE"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, simple and without much change:

`invoke-expression "'C:\Windows Services\MyService.exe'"`

using single quotations at the beginning and end of the path.

Comment: This worked for me when I needed to invoke a powershell script from bash and double quotes or triple double quotes weren't cutting it.

Answer (score 0):

Due to several [PowerShell quoting rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) that are used for [passing arguments to native commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing#passing-arguments-to-native-commands) which also have specific [experimental Features in PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/experimental-feature), quoting might get very confusing. Therefore the solution in some cases might be simply to ***don't* go down the rabbit hole**:

### Avoid quoting file paths with spaces by using the [8.3 filenames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename)

```
$FSO = New-Object -ComObject Scripting.FileSystemObject
$FSO.getfile('C:\Windows Services\MyService.exe').ShortPath
C:\WINDOW~1\MYSERV~1.EXE
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put `${yourpathtofile/folder}`

PowerShell does not count spaces; to tell PowerShell to consider the whole path including spaces, add your path in between `${` & `}`.

Answer (score -2):

Simply put the path in double quotes in front of cd, Like this:

> `cd "C:\Users\MyComputer\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects"`

Answer (score -2):

1. enter the root C drive by entering command

> **C:**

2. type **cd** and then press ***Tab key***, it will toggle through all available locations and press enter when you have reached the desired one

> **cd {press tab}**