# Batch process .png to .webp

Tags: image, bash, png, webp

I have around 100 `.png` images, and all of them have to be converted to `.webp` (Google's image format). I am using Google's CLI tool. Any idea how to batch process them.

Comment: Use `find ... -exec`

Comment: Just for future generation: `for F in *.jpg; do cwebp $F -o \`basename ${F%.jpg}\`.webp; done`

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can do it with a help of a simple `bash` script.

Navigate to the directory where your images reside and execute this:

```
$ for file in *
> do
> cwebp -q 80 "$file" -o "${file%.png}.webp"
> done
```

You can change the output file name, as you want. But should end with a `.webp` extension.

Comment: Where i can write this script?

Comment: @InfinitePrime, I just made a small edit to your answer. added quotes to the cwebp args (so your code doesn't break if there are spaces in the input file names)

Comment: Unfortunately this results in files named like `file.png.webp`, at least in my usage on Mingw.

Comment: on windows you can download cwebp binaries and use powershell to run it, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49602450/7448956

Comment: @aaawww or you can install a linux subsystem

Comment: @AdrianSmith You can use `for file in *.png ; do cwebp -q 50 "$file" -o "${file%.png}.webp"; done` to drop png from the output file extension.

Comment: @HaL Thank you sir. Question: "What is the function of the %" ?

Comment: Correct me if im wrong but this would result in a lossy compression, if you want to preserve the image in all its detail use ` -lossless -exact` flags instead of -q.

Comment: @HaL comment should be included in the answer. It's a really nice addition, dropping the original extension.

Comment: Online tools such as https://towebp.io can do the job instantly.

Comment: @HaL Minor update to your script. This version removes any extension from the output file name, not just .png: `for file in *
do
./cwebp -q 80 "$file" -o "${file%.*}.webp"
done`

Comment: I have created a GitHub reopsitory with this script and a step-by-step explanation on how to execute it: https://github.com/rene78/batch-convert-to-webp

Answer (score 39):

You need to use GNU Parallel if you have that many, or you will be there all year!

Please copy a few files into a spare temporary directory first and try this there to be sure it does what you want before using it on 100,000 images:

```
parallel -eta cwebp {} -o {.}.webp ::: *.png
```

That will start, and keep running, as many processes as you have CPU cores, each doing a `cwebp`. The files processed will be all the `PNG` files in the current directory.

If the command line gets too long, you can pass the file list in using `find` like this:

```
find . -name "*.png" | parallel -eta cwebp {} -o {.}.webp
```

Comment: @MarkSetchell Can you explain what the dot does? My command `find JPEG/ -iname "*.jpeg" -print -exec cwebp -jpeg_like -af {} -o Webp/{}.webp \;` works without the dot(Ubuntu). Thank you in advance. Googling didn't help. P.S. the dot refers to the first dot in `{.}.webp`

Comment: how to execution this command  and output  .webp in another folder

Comment: @Hosamalzagh You can just use `mkdir other/folder` then `parallel -eta cwebp {} -o other/folder/{} ::: *.png`

Comment: @saurabheights the dot in `{.}` removes the extension of the original match, outputting to `asdf.webp` instead of `asdf.jpeg.webp`

Comment: Online tools such as https://towebp.io can do the job instantly.