# Converting all png files from a folder to webp

Tags: r, png, webp

I can convert a single file from png format to webp using the following command:

```
library(png)
library(webp)

write_webp(
    image   = readPNG("fig1.png")
  , target  = "fig1.webp"
  , quality = 80
  )
```

Wondering how to convert all png files from a folder to webp using the R code something like below:

```
library(furrr)

list.files(
    path       = getwd()
  , pattern    = "*.png"
  , full.names = TRUE
  ) |> 
  future_map(
      .x      = 
    , .f      = write_webp
    , image   = readPNG("fig1.png")
    , target  = "fig1.webp"
    , quality = 80
    )
```

**Edited**

The following code is working for one .png file but don't work for more than one. Any hint please.

```
library(png)
library(webp)
library(furrr)
library(stringr)

FileNames <-
  list.files(
      path       = getwd()
    , pattern    = "*.png"
    , full.names = FALSE
    ) %>% 
    str_remove(
        string  = .
      , pattern = ".png"
      ) %>% 
    paste0(., ".webp")

FileNames

list.files(
    path       = getwd()
  , pattern    = "*.png"
  , full.names = TRUE
  ) %>% 
  future_map(
      .x        = 
    , .f        = readPNG
      ) %>%
  future_map(
      .x      = 
    , .f      = write_webp
    , target  = FileNames
    , quality = 80
      )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read all files in a folder and apply a function to each data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9564489/read-all-files-in-a-folder-and-apply-a-function-to-each-data-frame)

Comment: Is your issue the reading of all files or the change of format?

Comment: please consider reading the tag info for tidyverse before using it- the thing that comes up when you click on it is "*ONLY use this tag if your question relates to the installation, integration with your system, or inclusion of the entire tidyverse library. DO NOT USE if your question relates to one or two components of the tidyverse, such as dplyr or ggplot2. Use *those* tags, and tag with `r` as well for a better response.*

Comment: @Limey: Thanks for your comment. I do have the problem with `write_webp` function only. I was able to apply all other functions.

Comment: If you want it done simply, you can *"shell out"* with some type of `system()` command to **ImageMagick** and run `magick mogrify -format WEBP *.png`

Comment: If you have lots and want them converted in parallel, see here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26565297/2836621

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `sapply` to apply the function over a vector of files names. To make sure that the `target` is every time with the `.webp` extension you could use the `file_path_sans_ext` function to get the name without `.png` extension like this:

```r
library(png)
library(webp)

setwd("/Users/quinten/Downloads/test_folder_webp")
files <- dir(pattern = "png$")

sapply(files, \(x) {
  write_webp(
    image   = readPNG(x)
    , target  = paste0(tools::file_path_sans_ext(x),".webp")
    , quality = 80
  )
})
```

<sup>Created on 2023-10-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

When you check your folder you will see that the target files have been converted.

Answer (score 1):

On unix-alikes, in R you could use `cwebp` in Bash but send the command via `system`. This should be much faster than loading in R first. Command will be executed in working directory which you can specify using `setwd()`.

```
sprintf('cwebp -q 85 %s.png -o %s.webp -quiet', pfx, pfx) |> lapply(system)
```

where `-q 85` means quality which can be set from 1  to 100.

`pfx` are the prefixes of files to be converted, which you can define manually or `grep` or the like:

```
pfx <- grep('png$', dir(), value=TRUE) |> gsub(pat='.png', rep='')
```

Similar should also be possible on other OS'es.