# powershell passing argument with spaces

Tags: powershell, jar, arguments

so i have the problem that i'm trying to call a java application via powershell that has spaces in the file path.

Following command doesn't work and doesn't return any error or similar:

```
Start-Process java -ArgumentList '-jar', 'C:Program Files/test.jar'
```

I can't seem to get it working and hope you guys have recommendations for me

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spaces cause split in path with PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537098/spaces-cause-split-in-path-with-powershell)

Comment: Not exactly, since i'm passing arguments and not trying to directly call a program with & "C:/Program Files/test.exe"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673967/how-to-run-an-exe-file-in-powershell-with-parameters-with-spaces-and-quotes is it better?

Comment: Also tried that but still doesn't work :-/