# How to make powershell inline script path recognise spaces?

Tags: powershell, tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

The boss changed TFS servers and added a space in the `path: D:\TFS Agent\xxx` and it's causing my powershell script to fail upon release.

We have build/release automatic integration with `TFS` and I have an inline powershell task to read a file and convert it to `JSON` then execute some `SQL`. I had this working until this morning.

The problem is that the agent path is a system variable in `TFS: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` and I'm not sure how to handle the space in the path.

I've tried this:

```
# Begin inline script
Param(
    [string]$path,
    [string]$db,
    [string]$schema,
    [string]$envName
)
# Create module
$formattedPath = $path -replace " ", "` ";
$conv = Get-Content -Raw -Path "$formattedPath" | ConvertFrom-Json;
```

But all I get is D:\TFS. The path looks like this before the replace:

```
D:\TFS Agent\_work\r3\a\xxx
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to replace the space with a tick mark or how to ignore spaces. I'm very new to powershell so this may just be some simple thing, but my google-fu is not strong today. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: May be this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18537263/8534630

Comment: why is a space in the path breaking things..?  Are you trying to replace the space because there *isn't* a space in the actual path?  You should be able to run this as it is: `Get-Content -Path $path -Raw`

Comment: @ArunG I looked at that before and that's where I got the idea to replace. I'm not sure how to implement the ampersand, however.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I tried without the quotation marks like so: `$conv = Get-Content -Raw -Path $path | ConvertFrom-Json;` but I get the same error: `Cannot find path 'D:\TFS' because it does not exist.` Also there is a space in the actual path now, there wasn't before.

Comment: @kiasta Does your `$path` variable have embedded quotes `"`?

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 It's an argument being passed in the powershell task in tfs: `-path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` there are no quotation marks in the path being passed from me, not sure about the variable, however.

Comment: Is that an environment variable?  You should be able to access it: `$Env:DefaultWorkingDirectory`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 That was the solution, so apparently what was happening was that the log was showing the right path but when I Write-Output $path it was for some reason truncated to D:\TFS. I used the $env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY and that worked like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: *The path looks like this before the replace: `D:\TFS Agent\_work\r3\a\xxx`* What evidence of that do you have? Your `-replace` operation is effectively no-op. It replace space with space. If you only get `D:\TFS` in the result, then that mean you have only that from start.

Comment: @PetSerAl From the TFS log itself, it was showing the right path for the argument and I never Write-Output the $path variable because I assumed it was passing the right path: `2018-08-15T14:59:16.3135448Z ##[debug]Write-Output $path'
2018-08-15T14:59:16.3165515Z ##[debug]Env:INPUT_SCRIPTARGUMENTS: '-path D:\TFS Agent\_work\r3\a'
2018-08-15T14:59:16.3465484Z ##[command]& 'D:\TFS Agent\_work\_temp\tmp14B7.ps1' -path D:\TFS Agent\_work\r3\a
2018-08-15T14:59:16.3605498Z D:\TFS` But I wrote output and it was truncated.

Comment: `-path D:\TFS Agent\_work\r3\a` Why do you think this will pass `D:\TFS Agent\_work\r3\a` to `-path` parameter, but not `D:\TFS` will be passed to `-path` parameter and `Agent\_work\r3\a` will be passed as positional argument? Space is argument separator after all. Also if you think that `Write-Output $path` truncate displayed output, then why not print something else, like `$path.Length`?

Comment: Your replace is doing nothing - the first quotes `" "` are a space, and you are replacing it with the second `"\` "` which is a PowerShell escape sequence, and only special characters have any meaning with an escape backtick - `"\`n"` for example as a newline. Other characters, like space, are not changed by a backtick and end up the same. So you are replacing a space with a space, which changes nothing.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are pass $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) with the variable path as below:

```
-path $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
```

While, if `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` contains spaces (such as `D:\TFS Agent\_work\r3\a`), it will show divided the values into different lines by spaces (such as `D:\TFS Agent\_work\r3\a` will show in two lines with value `D:\TFS` and `Agent\_work\r3\a`). So the variable `$path` with the value in the first line (like `D:\TFS`).

To solve the problem, you just need to **add double quotes for `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)`**. So just change the argument in PowerShell task as:

```
-path "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
```