# Compilation terminated while compiling in visual studio code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 10, b = 15, c;
    c = a + b;
    printf("%d", c);

    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I tried to compile it produce error

```
gcc.exe: error: instruction: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: error: Arthematic: No such file or directory   
gcc.exe: error: declearation: No such file or directory
gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

[Error code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pP2Oq.png)

Comment: gcc is trying to compile file with whitespaces. Please rename your file (e.g. change whitespaces with underscores) and try again

Comment: You may want to see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537098/spaces-cause-split-in-path-with-powershell)

Answer (score 4):

Your shell command is malformed. You used

```
gcc instruction Arthematic declearation.c -o instruction Arthematic declearation
```

when you should have used

```
gcc "instruction Arthematic declearation.c" -o "instruction Arthematic declearation"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid using spaces in your file or directory name. If any of it contains spaces, than you should put it between "" marks.