# execute program in powershell with quotation marks in path

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to launch a program using powershell that is located in c:\program files

```
PS C:\mydir> "c:\program files\node18\npm" run test
At line:1 char:31
+ "c:\program files\node18\npm" run test
+                               ~~~
Unexpected token 'run' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

When I try enclosing the entire command with quotation marks, he simply echoes the command back:

```
PS C:\mydir> "c:\program files\node18\npm run test"
c:\program files\node18\npm run test
```

Finally the solution suggested in [Spaces cause split in path with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537098/spaces-cause-split-in-path-with-powershell)
is not working for me:

```
PS c:mypath> & "c:\program files\node18\npm run test"

& : The term 'c:\program files\node18\npm run test' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
le program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
.
 char:3
rogram files\node18\npm run test"
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
egoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (c:\program files\node18\npm run test:String) [], CommandNotFoundExcepti

lyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: `& "c:\program files\node18\npm run test"`

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM - Add an explanation of what's happening and why the querent needs the `&`, and propose it as an answer instead of a mere comment.

Comment: Not working. & "c:\program files\node18\npm run test"
& : The term 'c:\program files\node18\npm run test' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file....