# Launching a batch file with elevation via a PowerShell command from VBS

Tags: powershell, cmd, vbscript, quoting, process-elevation

any idea to fix the following that I have with my script?

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
 objShell.Run("powershell -Command "Start-Process 'cmd' -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '/c "C:\Temp\CAL.bat"'"")
```

Error: [Expected ')'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1vVk.png)

I took the idea from [Running Powershell from vbs with command as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448365/running-powershell-from-vbs-with-command-as-parameter), but my little experience with these things does not help me.

Comment: You need to escape the double-quotes by doubling them: `objShell.Run("powershell -Command ""Start-Process 'cmd' -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '/c ""C:\temp\CAL.vbs""'""")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to satisfy *VBScript*'s own syntax rules *first*:

  - `"` chars. embedded inside `"..."` must be escaped as `""`
- The resulting string must satisfy *PowerShell*'s syntax, which has two aspects:

  - Needing to `\`-escape `"` chars. that should be considered a verbatim part of the command(s) passed to the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter of [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI.

    - *Unescaped* `"` chars. are assumed to have purely syntactic function *on the command line*, and are *removed* during command-line parsing.
  - Needing to ensure that the resulting string - with the `\` before `"` removed - is valid PowerShell syntax.
- Thus, use `\""`

  - Note: In case the process launched via `Start-Process` is *another* PowerShell instance launched with (possibly implied) `-Command` (rather than a *batch file*, as in this case), *two* layers of escaping are required in the *inner* call: `\\\""`

Therefore:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run "powershell -Command ""Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList '/c \""C:\Temp\CAL.bat\""'"""
```

Note:

- Since `objShell.Run()` does *not* call via `cmd.exe`, there is no strict need to enclose the `-Command` argument in `""...""` overall, which makes the above command a bit more readable.
- However, not doing so subjects what are then technically *multiple* arguments to `-Command` to *whitespace normalization* (runs of multiple spaces are folded into a single space); while that is *typically* not a problem, it *can* be, namely if such multi-space runs must be preserved as part of what PowerShell should see as a string literal.
- In your specific case, since you're calling a *batch file*, you can further simplify your command for that reason: [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) accepts batch-file paths *directly* as executables, i.e. as the arguments to the (positionally implied) `-FilePath` parameter; therefore, omitting all *optional* quoting, the simplest formulation of your specific command is:

  ```
  Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
  objShell.Run "powershell -Command Start-Process C:\Temp\CAL.bat -Verb RunAs"
  ```

---

If you want the entire invocation to **run *invisibly***, there are two aspects:

- To hide the *immediately* launched process, pass `0` as the value of the 2nd parameter (`intWindowStyle`) to [`objShell.Run()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//d5fk67ky(v=vs.85)).
- To hide the *indirectly* launched process, via `Start-Process`, pass `-WindowStyle Hidden` to it.

Therefore:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run "powershell -Command Start-Process C:\Temp\CAL.bat -Verb RunAs -WindowStyle Hidden", 0
```

---

Separately, if you want the processes to **run *synchronously***, i.e. if you want the `object.Run()` call to wait until all launched processes have finished:

- Pass `true` as the value of the 3rd parameter (`bWaitOnReturn`) to `objShell.Run()` to make the *immediately* launched process execution synchronous.

  - Note: Doing so makes `object.Run()` *return the exit code* of that process; to capture it in VBScript code, use `(...)` around the arguments and assign the return value to a variable:

    ```
    exitCode = objShell.Run(..., ..., true)
    ```
- To also execute the *indirectly* launched process synchronously, i.e. the elevated one launched via `Start-Process -Verb RunAs`, pass `-Wait` to it.

  - To also capture the exit code of the elevated process, additionally pass the `-PassThru` switch, which makes `Start-Process` output a process-information object whose `.ExitCode` property you can access, and which you can pass to `exit`

Therefore, if you want **to *combine* invisible and synchronous execution**, as well as **capture the exit code**:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
exitCode = objShell.Run("powershell -Command exit (Start-Process C:\Temp\CAL.bat -Verb RunAs -WindowStyle Hidden -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode", 0, true)
```