# Running Powershell command from within VBScript. The third line of code doesn't run

Tags: powershell, vbscript, privilege-elevation, process-elevation

I am running the following code from VBScript:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")
objShell.run("powershell.exe -Command ""Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs""")
objShell.run("powershell.exe ""Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath C:\Windows\Test1\Sub1','C:\Test2'""")
```

I receive an elevation prompt.  After allowing, the last line of code doesn't run.

Separately, the following lines of code work fine in PowerShell.  The second line requires elevation, received from line 1,
`Powershell -Command "Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs" Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath 'C:\Test1\Sub1','C:\Test2'`

How can I combine these together in a script to run in VBScript?  I then want the PowerShell window to close or not open in the first place.

Tried combining them into one line and I also separated them.  Neither way works.

Comment: Your first `objShell.run` does not include `bWaitOnReturn` set to `True`, so the second `objShell.run` fires off immediately. But even with that parameter, the second `objShell.run` is not going to run elevated, as it's a separate process. It all has to be done as one command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Fundamentally, *no* (non-persisted) state is preserved across separate calls to [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI.
- Therefore, you need a *single* call to `powershell.exe` that both (a) creates an *elevated* process (using [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) `-Verb RunAs`) *and* (b) executes a command *in that process*.

  - To that end, you must *nest* `powershell.exe` calls, i.e., you must use `Start-Process -Verb RunAs` to invoke *another* `powershell.exe` inside of which you can perform the call that requires elevation.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76584777/45375) explains the required techniques in principle, but there's an additional escaping requirement here to make the call *robust*:

- On `powershell.exe`'s command line, `"` chars. that should be preserved *as part of the command to execute* being passed to `-Command` must be `\`-escaped; combined with VBScript's escaping: `\""`.
- Due to using *nested* `powershell.exe` calls, *another* layer of `\`-escaping is required in order to preserve `"` chars. as part of the command in the *nested* call, if you want to pass your file paths *enclosed in `"..."`*
  : combined with VBScript's escaping: `\\\""`

  - Note: While `"..."` enclosure isn't strictly necessary here, it is generally required for robustly passing arbitrary file-system paths; while `'...'` enclosure is syntactically easier, because it doesn't require escaping, it breaks with paths that happen to contain `'` themselves)

Applying all the techniques from the linked answer - hidden, synchronous execution with exit-code capturing - to your use case:

```vb
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

exitCode = objShell.Run("powershell.exe -Command exit (Start-Process -PassThru -Wait -WindowStyle Hidden -Verb RunAs powershell.exe 'Add-MpPreference -ExclusionPath \\\""C:\Windows\Test1\Sub1\\\"", \\\""C:\Test2\\\""').ExitCode", 0, true)

WScript.Echo "The PowerShell call reported the following exit code: " & exitCode
```

Comment: @user692942, to my own bafflement - given how recently I wrote the linked answer - I had forgotten about it, otherwise I wouldn't have rewritten the overlapping content from scratch here. I've removed the overlapping content in favor of linking to the previous answer, focusing on what's specific to this question.

Comment: @user692942, it feels like we've had the discussion about sign posts vs. legitimate variations that warrant their own answer before, and I understand that your preference is to make everything a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/15770599/45375.
To me that does a disservice to the community, given the complexities of the PowerShell CLI, both alone and in combination with VBScript.