# Force a PowerShell script to be run as administrator

Tags: powershell

I have written a powershell script that installs and starts some services. It will only work if the script is run as administrator. Is there any way force a script to have those privileges?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566969/showing-the-uac-prompt-in-powershell-if-the-action-requires-elevation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the case you are using PowerShell V2 You can also do the following :

```
Start-Process "$psHome\powershell.exe" -Verb Runas -ArgumentList '-command "Get-Service"'
```

This would run "Get-Service" as administrator, you can replace it with your script.

Answer (score 0):

You might look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566969/showing-the-uac-prompt-in-powershell-if-the-action-requires-elevation). It allows you to force something to be run as another account.