# Make a powershell script aimt uac elevated priviledges?

Tags: powershell, uac, elevated-privileges, privilege-elevation

I have written a command which run a powershell script as an elevated user of the 'Domain Admins' group.

I want this script to aim UAC elevated privileges it is requiring, since this script should be able to perform administrative tasks.  I want it to ask then, possibly popping Windows to the currently logged user, which has launched my command.

How to mark a powershell script as requiring elevated priviliedges if UAC is activated.

I'm using standard output and error as log, it would be nice to keep them.

Cordially,

Comment: maybe this post is of interest for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566969/showing-the-uac-prompt-in-powershell-if-the-action-requires-elevation